# poedit does not see language in jquery

Tags: jquery, poedit

In below jQuery I need the language taken with poedit. But it does not see/recognize this. In the settings I have include the right file.
Also tried with "" and without "", none works.

Question: what do I do wrong? Thanks for your reply in advance.

```
jQuery('input[name="add_button"]').after('<div class="exceed"><?php echo __('Sorry You have exceed maximum limits', 'rdp-plugin') ?>"</div>');
```

Comment: Have you configured Poedit to scan whatever file extension and path your source code file has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) alias is `_()` (one underscore) not `__()` (two underscores). If you want Poedit to scan custom functions you need to add them to catalogue properties in the *Keywords* tab:

[image: Keywords]

Comment: strange the strings within all the .php do get into poedit but the jquery does not work. Not with _(), __() , _e()

Comment: Well... Remember that we cannot peek your monitor over your shoulder. We're still waiting for the details about the file extension and path.

Comment: In the header I finally see that there are to rows are missing. The X-Poedit-KeywordsLis was only declared with a __, _e "X-Poedit-WPHeader: rdp-plugin.php\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"

"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: __;_e;_n:1,2;_x:1,2c;_ex:1,2c;_nx:4c,1,2;esc_attr__;"
"esc_attr_e;esc_attr_x:1,2c;esc_html__;esc_html_e;esc_html_x:1,2c;_n_noop:1,2;"
"_nx_noop:3c,1,2;__ngettext_noop:1,2\n" 
Now it is working correctly. Thansk everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You need to describe your situation [better](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html) — if you don’t provide enough information to *reproduce*, it’s impossible to correctly guess of your actual issue. But Poedit certainly doesn’t somehow blacklist jQuery-using code.

*If* you have this code in a JavaScript file (jQuery is simply an API, you seem to think it’s a language of its own), then Poedit sees it as a JavaScript file and there you have simply a *string literal*, not a `__()` call and so Poedit of course won’t see it as a call.

Comment: I have tried to understand what you suggest, but without an example how to use it in above mentioned query I have no idea how to code it now.
Hope you can help me with an example. I appreciate it. Thanks.